# query on how Java ++ val and val++ works

Tags: java, operators

```
public class Testtt {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        int x = 1;

        System.out.println(x++ + ++x + ++x);

    }

}

Result is 8
```

how it prints 8 .. can any one please explain it ? o.O
sorry to ask dumb question but i didnt get how the pre - post increment works

Answer (score 4):

x++ returns 1, value of x is now 2
++x now returns 3, value of x is now 3
++x now returns 4, value of x is now 4
The returned values (1, 3 and 4) all add up to 8.

Comment: thank you sir :)
got it now

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(x++ + ++x + ++x);
```

1.) x++ => x = 1, increement later

2.) ++x => x =3, increement from step 1 , increement again for `++x`

3.) ++x => x=4, increement again for `++x`

```
finally - 1 + 3 + 4
```

Answer (score 2):

x++ increments after x value is used and ++x increments before x value is used
I try to explain it using an example:

```
int x = 1;
System.out.println(x++); // prints 1 but its value will be 2 after print
x = 1;
System.out.println(++x); // prints 2 but its value will be 2 after print
System.out.println(x++ + ++x + ++x); // 1 + 3 + 4 = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`++x` is called preincrement 
`x++` is called postincrement

Example:

```
int x = 1, y = 1;

System.out.println(++x); // outputs 2
System.out.println(x); // outputs 2

System.out.println(y++); // outputs 1
System.out.println(y); // outputs 2
```

I can explain `x++ + ++x + ++x` by `1 + 3 + 4 = 8`